# Return children of Realm RLMResults<Object> instead of <Object>'s when filtering

Tags: ios, realm

Example Realm relationship:
`People.Dogs.FavouriteFoods`
that are strictly one way -> RLMArrays

**I have:**

`let result = RLMResult<People>` from a previous operation.

and I have an array of FavouriteFood.IDs that a user selected

`let selectedIDs: [String]`

Now I am trying to filter/predicate this result, but instead of returning `People`, which I already have, I am trying to get out the FavouriteFood objects that intersect with the `selectedIDs` I can only find guides that explain how to sort/filter on `RLMResults<People>` where the result is `People` i.e. the same as the generic type on RLMResult.

My goal is to, in the end, construct a list where I can say "Out of the 14 FavouriteFoods Person A's Dogs have, 7 of them are in the selectedIDs list" etc. for Person B, C, D...

I want something like: `"ANY dogs.favouriteFoods.ID in selectedIDs"` but it should return all the FavouriteFoods matching the predicate for an individual Person, instead of all the People having Dogs having these particular favouriteFoods.

Is this possible to do as a predicate? Is there a way to flip the concept to ask for FavouriteFoods instead, or must I loop over all people, dogs, favouriteFoods and manually tally this up?

Thanks for any help given.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the question but let me ask this: Assuming you have a list of favorite foods, and one of those is 'biscuit'. Do you currently have a way to *query favorite foods* to return the dogs whose 'biscuit' is their favorite food?

Comment: @Jay No sadly not, I was trying to express that by saying the relationships are strictly one-way. Yeah, if there was such a parent relationship it would have been a lot simpler to just loop over all Foods that matches and then filter by first Dogs then People. I suspect the data has been exported from a different database into Realm and that those kind of relations have all be flattened :/

Comment: Your explanation was good, just wanted to make sure. You've got a few options. One possibility is; since you know the one-way relationship, load all of that data in and create the inverse relationship. e.g. load in a person, and then iterate over their dogs list. For each dog you know it's favorite food so add an inverse relationship property to the food and then update it to point back to the dog. A second option is to generate list of objects by iterating over your dataset. It's pretty inefficient but would be workable. How much data is it? 100 objects? 1M objects?

Comment: around 200k, so enough to warrant a little caution with the implementation. This is usually not a problem with Realm, as long as I can boil it down to a manageable RLMResult before starting to loop over children and pulling them into memory. But in this case, I can't see how. As soon as I start nesting the loops O(n) goes to O(n squared)